# Apple Watch losing connection to iOS app after 15 minutes

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

My WatchKit extension makes heavy use of openParentApplication to load data and images into the WatchKit app, as adviced by Apple. This is working fine, especially after using the clever advice here:
http://www.fiveminutewatchkit.com/blog/2015/3/11/one-weird-trick-to-fix-openparentapplicationreply

However, it's only working for about 15 minutes. After that, the WatchKit extension fails to wake up the iPhone application in the background and the iOS AppDelegate handleWatchKitExtensionRequest is never called. If I manually open the iPhone app, the call gets through and it answers directly to the WatchKit extension, but that is hardly something I can ask the user to do... I want the WatchKit app to usable without having to manually wake up the iOS app every 15 minutes.

I'm using iOS 8.2 on the testing device, Swift and Xcode 6.2. Maybe it could be related to using a developer provisioning profile? Anyone else out there having experienced this?

Code used in utility class WatchUtils, this is used on several occations in the app:

```
class func openPhoneApp(userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], complete:(reply:[NSObject : AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void) {
    WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(userInfo, reply: { (reply:[NSObject : AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        complete(reply:reply, error:error)
    })
}
```

openPhoneApp is used like this:

```
WatchUtils.openPhoneApp(requestData, complete: { (reply, error) -> Void in
    if let reply = reply {
        // Do stuff
    }
})
```

AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {

    // Bogus task for keeping app going
    var bogusTask = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler { () -> Void in
    }
    // End bogus task after 2 seconds
    delay(2.0, closure: { () -> () in 
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(bogusTask)
    })

    // Code here for collecting information from phone app
    // ...
    var replyDict:[NSObject : AnyObject] = ["userHighscore":45]
    reply(replyDict)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(bogusTask) // End the bogusTask in case the work was faster than 2 seconds
}

// Utility function for delay
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        closure
    )
}
```

Comment: show your code, how & where you are requesting the Parent App `openParentApplication`...???

Comment: Hi Zubair, thanks for your reply. Updated original post with with code.

Comment: haven't you set any timer for this Parent App Call....???

Comment: Do some checking on the error in the block. Sometimes it gets failed with some reasons. That's why you have an error object sent from the system.

Comment: No timers. Everything works fine for about 15 minutes, and then all of a sudden, the WatchKit Extension doesn't get any answers any more. The iOS app is stable and going fine in the background, but the WatchKit Extension just can't wake it up. Until I manually open the app on my phone, then the reply comes quickly.

Comment: Thankyou Ashraf. I have checked for errors. The thing here though is that the AppDelegates handleWatchKitExtensionRequest doesn't even get called.

Comment: Instead of using the delay, have you tried ending the background task only after you've replied (as intended)? I seem to recall developer forum posts that indicate the timing methods have either changed and/or no longer work as they did in 8.2.

Comment: M@MikeSwanson If you ever find those posts I would be interested in seeing them :-)

Comment: I also had this issue. Another test is restart the phone, open the watch kit app and see if works. I found the use of NSLogger to be very helpful in establishing this was the issue. Sadly, I didn't find a fix, but was lucky enough that I could run all my code in the watch kit extension instead.

Comment: Thanks for your advice everyone. @GaryRiches, did your watchkit extension do any network calls? It's adviced from Apple that network communication should be done via openParentApplication in the iPhone app, right, but maybe this isn't necessary? Maybe I should do my networking in the extension as well.

Comment: @hobert My entire app is solely network calls: https://youtu.be/poValYfohLg I don't need to wait for any responses from them. The app is _much_ better from making the calls from the extension. It's been approved so there is nothing against doing it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I think I will do the same.

Comment: Exact same behavior here. App works 100% in simulator but on the watch itself I have to manually launch the app for the calls to get through after X minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and reading the docs fixed it for me. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:

> Because this method is likely to be called while your app is in the background, call the beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler: method at the start of your implementation and the endBackgroundTask: method after you have processed the reply and executed the reply block. Starting a background task ensures that your app is not suspended before it has a chance to send its reply.

Some of my code:

```
    nint taskId = 0;
    public override void HandleWatchKitExtensionRequest (UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<NSDictionary> reply)
    {
        try {
            taskId= UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask(delegate
                {    //this is the action that will run when the task expires                       
                });
            if (userInfo != null && userInfo.Keys [0] != null && userInfo.Keys [0].ToString() == "match") {

                MyWebClient wc = new MyWebClient ();
                wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) => {
                    String res = e.Result;
                    reply (new NSDictionary (                   
                        "justTesting", new NSString (res)
                    ));
                    if(taskId != 0)                               
                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskId);
                };
                wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(myUrl));
            }
       }
```

After I changed to doing this it has been rock stable for days for me while previously it always stopped working after 5-15 minutes.